# no init file importing in scriptname in vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to config my vim and installing some plugins to my editor. despite of installing Plug install with wget file. it doesn't load. my .vimrc file isn't in script names list.

Edited:

I created ~/.vimrc file. the text is :

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plug 'williamboman/mason.nvim'
Plug 'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim'
Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
call plug#end()
```

:scriptnames list :
1: /usr/share/n

```
vim/runtime/filetype.vim
  2: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
  3: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/indent.vim
  4: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
  5: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
  6: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
  7: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim
  8: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/health.vim
  9: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/man.vim
 10: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/matchit.vim
 11: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
 12: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/rplugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/shada.vim
 16: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/spellfile.vim
 17: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tohtml.vim
 19: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/tutor.vim
 20: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

I installed pluginstall using this command :

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

the .vim folder tree is :

```
.vim
├── autoload
│   └── plug.vim
└── bundle
    └── Vundle.vim
```

Comment: This needs a lot more information.

Comment: what else should I add ?

Comment: The content of your ".vimrc", its location, the output of `:script`, whatever command you executed in your shell, the full version of Vim, etc.

Comment: tnx for your patience. I added al the details I could.

Comment: Neovim is not Vim. You don't configure one the same way you configure the other so pick your poison: do you want to configure **Vim** or do you want to configure **Neovim**?

Comment: I checked bot. but here are just the steps that are essential for vim. just maybe the packages are wrong but the problem is one step behind. I can not run :PlugInstall in vim. As you see my vimrc and also my autoload package doesn't exist in :scriptnames.

Comment: `:scriptnames` prints out Neovim paths and all your config is done in Vim paths. This means that you are configuring Neovim as if it were Vim or that you are testing your Vim config in Neovim. So, **again**, do you want to configure **Vim** or **Neovim**? And why do you have both vundle and vim-plug?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the config, you are using `mason.nvim`, then you must use neovim, not vim. Even your configuration directory is wrong, nvim require its configuration be placed in directory `~/.config/nvim`, not under `~/.vim`.

Also you should delete the directory `bundle` and all file under it, since you are using vim-plug to manage your plugins (make sure you have run `PlugInstall` to install the plugins).